# Establish One-Many Relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables and I need to establish a 1-many relation among them, as an example:
1 Customer can have many Order(s). 
What is a good way to create keys on the Order table such that there can be many rows in Orders, relating to one/same Customer details? i.e  can I have cases when there are 2 rows with same CustomerID inserted into Order (1-many relation on CustomerID foreign key)

Assume 
Customer table has columns:

```
CustomerID (key)
Name 
OtherColumns
```

Order:

```
<IsaKeyNeeded>
customerID (foreign key) 
OrderName
```

Another question I have is does 'Order' need to have it's own key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it set up correctly ... the Order table should have a foreign key to the Customer table.  This establishes the relationship of one customer to many orders.  Just do not make the CustomerID a unique key.

To answer your other question ... yes, the Order table should have it's own primary key.

Comment: What about cleaning up the Order table, will it be done easily or do I  have to first remove the foreign key relationship, I have to truncate all the tables periodically. If I have a primary key on Orders, can I insert it automatically as an int or something. I have Customers input coming in from a .txt file and Orders are comma separated, as part of a Customers details.

Comment: is it possible to not make CustomerID a unique key (it still needs to be a key, so it should be unique?)

Comment: defining the primary key column as an "int identity" will automatically create a unique id for your Orders table for you.  Use GUIDs if you have to span multiple databases with the same data though.

Comment: thanks. I have two stackoverflow account and am trying to merge them. Miraculously this one worked after a long time. Any idea where I can ask for this?

Comment: You can delete all entries in the order table without violating the foreign key.  As paquetp stated, you can use the identity property to make the Order PK auto increment.  Yes, as I mentioned in the original answer, do not make the CustomerID a unique key.  Foreign keys do not have to be unique keys in the child table.